# open sharepoint file without checking out

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript

I need to link our existing system to our sharepoint site for retrieving documents.

I can open a document from the site however when i do I get a window asking if i want to 'Check out & Open' or just 'Open'.

How can i set this value within my code so documents are always just opened without being checked out.

This is my code:

```
Dim runFile
Dim rsDoc

Set rsDoc = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsDoc.Open "Select xalFileName as Filename from DocumentLinks where xalReference = '"&Trim(controls("M1TextBox1").Value&"'"), Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText

If rsDoc.EOF Then
    Call App.MessageBox("The document code is not valid, please speak to Keith",vbInformation,"Data updated")

Else
    Do While Not rsDoc.EOF
        sFile = rsDoc.Fields("Filename")

        Set runFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            runFile.Run Chr(34) & sFile & Chr(34), 1, False
        Set runFile = Nothing

        rsDoc.MoveNext
        Loop
End If
rsDoc.Close
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ok, duly noted. I wasn't aware of that and just wanted the make the title more specific to the question.